# Checkerboard challenge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm close to solving this challenge, however, I cannot figure out how to refactor my code to get the following spec to pass.

**Spec to pass:**

```
Test.assert_equals(checkered_board(2), "\u25A1 \u25A0\n\u25A0 \u25A1")
```

**My error:**

`Expected: "\u25A1 \u25A0\n\u25A0 \u25A1", instead got: "\u25A1 \u25A0 \n\u25A0 \u25A1 "`

**My attempt** (via visual on repl.it, everything appears correct)

```
def checkered_board(dimension)

  return false unless dimension.integer? && dimension >= 2 


  checkboard = nil
  checker_array = []
  count = dimension



    while dimension % 2 == 0 && count > 0 # set-up for even number passed in
        if count % 2 == 0
            checkboard = ("\u25A1 \u25A0 ") * (dimension / 2)
            checkboard += "\n"
            checker_array << checkboard
            count -= 1
        else
            checkboard = ("\u25A0 \u25A1 ") * (dimension / 2)
            if count == 1 #if count is the last number before 0, do not add \n to pass spec
               checker_array << checkboard
            else
               checkboard += "\n"
               checker_array << checkboard
            end
            count -= 1
        end

    end 

    while dimension % 2 == 1 && count > 0 # set-up for odd number passed in

        if count % 2 == 1  
            checkboard = ("\u25A0 \u25A1 ") * (dimension / 2)
            checkboard += "\u25A0"
            if count == 1 #if count is the last number before 0, do not add \n to pass spec
               checker_array << checkboard
            else
               checkboard += "\n"
               checker_array << checkboard
            end
            count -= 1
        else
            checkboard = ("\u25A1 \u25A0 ") * (dimension / 2)
            checkboard += "\u25A1"
            checkboard += "\n"
            checker_array << checkboard
            count -= 1
        end
    end

checkboard = checker_array.join("")
checkboard


end
```

What should I add/do to pass how the `\n` is within the required passing spec?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my own problem and solution is commented in code below

```
def checkered_board(dimension)

  return false unless dimension.is_a?(Integer) && dimension >= 2 


  checkboard = nil
  checker_array = []
  spacer = " "
  count = dimension



    while dimension % 2 == 0 && count > 0 # set-up for even number passed in
        if count % 2 == 0
            checkboard = ("\u25A1#{spacer}\u25A0#{spacer}") * (dimension / 2)
            checkboard = checkboard[0..-2] + "\n" #solution was here
            checker_array << checkboard
            count -= 1
        else
            checkboard = ("\u25A0#{spacer}\u25A1#{spacer}") * (dimension / 2)
            if count == 1 #if count is the last number before 0, do not add \n to pass spec
                checker_array << checkboard[0..-2] #solution was here
            else
                checkboard = checkboard[0..-2] + "\n" #solution was here
                checker_array << checkboard
            end
            count -= 1
        end

    end 

    while dimension % 2 == 1 && count > 0 # set-up for odd number passed in

        if count % 2 == 1  
            checkboard = ("\u25A0#{spacer}\u25A1#{spacer}") * (dimension / 2)
            checkboard += "\u25A0"
            if count == 1 #if count is the last number before 0, do not add \n to pass spec
               checker_array << checkboard[0..-1] #solution was here
            else
               checkboard += "\n"
               checker_array << checkboard
            end
            count -= 1
        else
            checkboard = ("\u25A1#{spacer}\u25A0#{spacer}") * (dimension / 2)
            checkboard += "\u25A1"
            checkboard = checkboard[0..-1] + "\n" #solution was here
            checker_array << checkboard
            count -= 1
        end
    end

checkboard = checker_array.join("")
checkboard


end
```